# MySQL Query - how to select rows based on range value

Tags: php, mysql

Having a bit of an issue with this one. Is there a way to check if a value is in the range provided in a mysql query result.

How can I see if the Zip Code 85012 is within the ZipCodes field returned without first making a query, breaking it up into parts, and using BETWEEN?

```
+---------+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+
| StyleID | HistStyleID | AutobuilderStyleID | FilterRule | ZipCodes    |
+---------+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+
|  355755 |  2013490103 | w2013k49m1t3       | includes   | 27000-36999 |
+---------+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------------+
```

:: UPDATE ::

This table can also contain various ranges as follows..

```
+---------+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| StyleID | HistStyleID | AutobuilderStyleID | FilterRule | ZipCodes                            |
+---------+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
|  332492 |  2012493107 | w2012k49m31t7      | excludes   | 38600-39799,70000-71499,71600-79999 |
+---------+-------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Does you Zipcodes field holds just 2 zipcodes or more than that? Any ways it looks shabby.

Comment: Looking at the table it can be various ranges.

38600-39799,70000-71499,71600-79999

Comment: This sounds like a table normalization problem. I would probably add a table that relates to this table and has ZipCodeRangeStart and ZipCodeRangeEnd fields. You could then JOIN that table to this based on the value you are interested being `BETWEEN` those values.

Comment: This database is from Chrome Data so redesign is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Like it's been suggested in the comments, you should redesign your database:

```
CREATE TABLE Styles (
     StyleID INT PRIMARY KEY,
     HistStyleID INT, 
     AutobuilderStyleID VARCHAR(40),
     FilterRule VARCHAR(40)
)


CREATE TABLE ZipCodes (
     StyleID INT,
     RangeBegin INT,
     RangeEnd INT,

     FOREIGN KEY StyleID REFERENCES Styles(StyleID)
)
```

Then you can make queries like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT StyleID FROM ZipCodes WHERE RangeBegin >= 85012 AND RangeEnd <= 85012
```